# Impersonation Issue on IIS7 - Entity Framework Trusted_Connection ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, iis, impersonation, kerberos

I'm developing an ASP.NET Application that connects to a Database (on another machine). When I try to connect from my machine there are no problem, when I deploy it on the destination environment, EF returns an exception:

```
The underlying provider failed on Open.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) at
```

My configuration is:

```
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication useKernelMode="false">
                <extendedProtection tokenChecking="None" />
            </windowsAuthentication>
        </authentication>
    </security>
```

And my connection string is:

```
 <add name="pmgbicopEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/copDB.csdl|res://*/copDB.ssdl|res://*/copDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=[NAME]\devde;Initial Catalog=[NAME];Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

If I remove the database instruction the this.Page.User is my current Account (and this is right!), but when I open a new connection via EF I become "Anonymous"

I tried with impersonation like:

```
WindowsIdentity winId = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;
try
{
  ctx = winId.Impersonate();
  //EF SOMETHING
}
catch (Exception exx)
{
}
finally
{
  if (ctx != null)
  ctx.Undo();
}
```

But I get the same exception "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'."

I tried to change the application pool user, tried to impersonate manually but without any success.

The IIS configuration has some kerberos stuff that I tried to Enable and Disable but nothing change.

Do you have any suggestion? Do I have to enable something like "trust" between machines? For my development machine from "fake IIS" I have no problem but my user is enabled on the DB.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you on an Active Directory domain? If so then you'll need to set up permissions within SQL Server so that the client machine (the web server) can access the database. Try `CREATE LOGIN [MyDomain\MyComputer$] FROM WINDOWS;`

Answer (score 0):

What is your end goal here:  pass through the user's credentials to SQL or use a predetermined account to connect to SQL?

Here are the settings I've had to configure Kerberos to work (which allows you to use the user's account permissions):

IIS Settings:

```
-Physical Path Credentials:  Application User (pass-through authentication)
-Physical Path Credential Logon Type:  Clear Text
-Application Pool ID:  Domain\ServiceAccount
-Integrated Windows Authentication:  Enabled
-Windows Authentication Providers:  Negotiate
-useAppPoolCredentials (found in Configuration Editor):  True
```

SPN created for the ServiceAccount:
*SETSPN -L Domain\ServiceAccount*

HTTP/Our.WebSiteURL.com

If you want don't want to use a domain service account replace that with Domain\MachineAccount in both the SPN and Application Pool.